# Bad Media Description when I try make call between two JSSIP clients

Tags: javascript, sip, kamailio, jssip

I'm trying make a call between two JSSIP clients. Both of them in the same machine on Google Chrome browser (I saw some differences on the Mozilla console). Immediatelly after confirm the call it's closed. In the log message I saw "Bad Media Description".

My server works fine with another SIP clients as Empathy.

Do you have any idea how to solver that problem?

*JSSIP: 3.0.13

*Server: Kamailio 5.0.2

Log:
[...]

```
    +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface send() +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface received WebSocket message +217ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport received text message:

    SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
    Via: SIP/2.0/WSS s56b8ft8a202.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK8669084;rport=52968;received=user_ip
    To: ;tag=97d77c4d4e4d9a8d8b41049b8ede099b.4796
    From: ;tag=qcvbh2r34r
    Call-ID: coe93q67b4ugtlgphrhmkn
    CSeq: 1 REGISTER
    WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="mydomain.com", nonce="Wa7pDFmu5+CalBwcznKJJ6+bCbr5AM2o"
    Server: kamailio (5.0.2 (x86_64/linux))
    Content-Length: 0


     +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:DigestAuthentication authenticate() | response generated +22ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport send() +2ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport sending message:

    REGISTER sip:mydomain.com SIP/2.0
    Via: SIP/2.0/WSS s56b8ft8a202.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK980551
    Max-Forwards: 69
    To: 
    From: ;tag=qcvbh2r34r
    Call-ID: coe93q67b4ugtlgphrhmkn
    CSeq: 2 REGISTER
    Authorization: Digest algorithm=MD5, username="studio", realm="mydomain.com", nonce="Wa7pDFmu5+CalBwcznKJJ6+bCbr5AM2o", uri="sip:mydomain.com", response="d9fda5617bfdcdd8ae64ede8b514ae6e"
    Contact: ;+sip.ice;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="";expires=600
    Expires: 600
    Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER,INFO
    Supported: path,gruu,outbound
    User-Agent: JsSIP 3.0.13
    Content-Length: 0


     +0ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface send() +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface received WebSocket message +219ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport received text message:

    SIP/2.0 200 OK
    Via: SIP/2.0/WSS s56b8ft8a202.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK980551;rport=52968;received=user_ip
    To: ;tag=97d77c4d4e4d9a8d8b41049b8ede099b.aa58
    From: ;tag=qcvbh2r34r
    Call-ID: coe93q67b4ugtlgphrhmkn
    CSeq: 2 REGISTER
    Contact: ;expires=533;received="sip:user_ip:40814;transport=ws";+sip.instance="";reg-id=1, ;expires=600;received="sip:user_ip:52968;transport=ws";+sip.instance="";reg-id=1
    Server: kamailio (5.0.2 (x86_64/linux))
    Content-Length: 0


     +1ms
    studio.html:75 Aqui tá registrado
    studio.html:76 Fazendo chamada...
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:UA call() +10ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession new +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession connect() +0ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession newRTCSession() +290ms
    studio.html:105 **************
    studio.html:106 {originator: "local", session: RTCSession, request: OutgoingRequest}
    [Violation] 'message' handler took 307ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession emit "peerconnection" +282ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession session connecting +0ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession emit "connecting" +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession createLocalDescription() +0ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession emit "sdp" +50s
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession emit "sending" [request:OutgoingRequest] +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport send() +4ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport sending message:

    INVITE sip:cliente@mydomain.com SIP/2.0
    Via: SIP/2.0/WSS s56b8ft8a202.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK3599232
    Max-Forwards: 69
    To: 
    From: ;tag=l4h1ovlld6
    Call-ID: 8g0sieoec4p8l4vrm1s6
    CSeq: 4973 INVITE
    Contact: 
    Content-Type: application/sdp
    Session-Expires: 90
    Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER,INFO
    Supported: timer,ice,replaces,outbound
    User-Agent: JsSIP 3.0.13
    Content-Length: 4562

    v=0
    o=- 6638472907486122365 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    s=-
    t=0 0
    a=group:BUNDLE audio video
    a=msid-semantic: WMS dUJ22POkI6U9YcoQ7v98q6osirNG6TZCbVhx
    m=audio 59208 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
    c=IN IP4 user_ip
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=candidate:2017461514 1 udp 2122262783 2804:d49:c4f:7f00:3d04:9c24:2401:1d42 59353 typ host generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:3022624816 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.1.4 59208 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:918813178 1 tcp 1518283007 2804:d49:c4f:7f00:3d04:9c24:2401:1d42 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:4205470912 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.1.4 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:494278629 1 udp 1685987071 user_ip 59208 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.4 rport 59208 generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
    a=ice-ufrag:60LN
    a=ice-pwd:tuTNIbAEQw/mkZX/vYKmsdM1
    a=ice-options:trickle
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 6F:B8:BF:D1:54:8F:3F:5C:5F:23:0D:48:4D:91:DC:12:CB:C3:08:73:F6:C7:CF:8E:F6:63:75:AC:C7:DB:97:5A
    a=setup:actpass
    a=mid:audio
    a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
    a=sendrecv
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
    a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
    a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
    a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
    a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
    a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
    a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
    a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
    a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
    a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
    a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
    a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
    a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
    a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
    a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
    a=ssrc:1472011457 cname:crtk8ri1ZT46Zj4D
    a=ssrc:1472011457 msid:dUJ22POkI6U9YcoQ7v98q6osirNG6TZCbVhx 86b888be-6f9a-4972-9fa7-1563d105d285
    a=ssrc:1472011457 mslabel:dUJ22POkI6U9YcoQ7v98q6osirNG6TZCbVhx
    a=ssrc:1472011457 label:86b888be-6f9a-4972-9fa7-1563d105d285
    m=video 33253 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98 100 102 127 97 99 101 125
    c=IN IP4 user_ip
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=candidate:2017461514 1 udp 2122262783 2804:d49:c4f:7f00:3d04:9c24:2401:1d42 43405 typ host generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:3022624816 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.1.4 33253 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:918813178 1 tcp 1518283007 2804:d49:c4f:7f00:3d04:9c24:2401:1d42 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:4205470912 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.1.4 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:494278629 1 udp 1685987071 user_ip 33253 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.4 rport 33253 generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
    a=ice-ufrag:60LN
    a=ice-pwd:tuTNIbAEQw/mkZX/vYKmsdM1
    a=ice-options:trickle
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 6F:B8:BF:D1:54:8F:3F:5C:5F:23:0D:48:4D:91:DC:12:CB:C3:08:73:F6:C7:CF:8E:F6:63:75:AC:C7:DB:97:5A
    a=setup:actpass
    a=mid:video
    a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
    a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
    a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
    a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
    a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
    a=sendrecv
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtcp-rsize
    a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
    a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
    a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
    a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
    a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
    a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
    a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
    a=rtpmap:102 red/90000
    a=rtpmap:127 ulpfec/90000
    a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:97 apt=96
    a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:99 apt=98
    a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:101 apt=100
    a=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:125 apt=102
    a=ssrc-group:FID 1005898268 1803705457
    a=ssrc:1005898268 cname:crtk8ri1ZT46Zj4D
    a=ssrc:1005898268 msid:dUJ22POkI6U9YcoQ7v98q6osirNG6TZCbVhx 700a8532-4147-4891-9bad-e1446d27a7e3
    a=ssrc:1005898268 mslabel:dUJ22POkI6U9YcoQ7v98q6osirNG6TZCbVhx
    a=ssrc:1005898268 label:700a8532-4147-4891-9bad-e1446d27a7e3
    a=ssrc:1803705457 cname:crtk8ri1ZT46Zj4D
    a=ssrc:1803705457 msid:dUJ22POkI6U9YcoQ7v98q6osirNG6TZCbVhx 700a8532-4147-4891-9bad-e1446d27a7e3
    a=ssrc:1803705457 mslabel:dUJ22POkI6U9YcoQ7v98q6osirNG6TZCbVhx
    a=ssrc:1803705457 label:700a8532-4147-4891-9bad-e1446d27a7e3

     +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface send() +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface received WebSocket message +255ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport received text message:

    SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required
    Via: SIP/2.0/WSS s56b8ft8a202.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK3599232;rport=52968;received=user_ip
    To: ;tag=97d77c4d4e4d9a8d8b41049b8ede099b.15d4
    From: ;tag=l4h1ovlld6
    Call-ID: 8g0sieoec4p8l4vrm1s6
    CSeq: 4973 INVITE
    Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="mydomain.com", nonce="Wa7pP1mu6BO4W5JXkW+Nxa7oljqc0vr5"
    Server: kamailio (5.0.2 (x86_64/linux))
    Content-Length: 0


     +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport send() +8ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport sending message:

    ACK sip:cliente@mydomain.com SIP/2.0
    Via: SIP/2.0/WSS s56b8ft8a202.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK3599232
    To: ;tag=97d77c4d4e4d9a8d8b41049b8ede099b.15d4
    From: ;tag=l4h1ovlld6
    Call-ID: 8g0sieoec4p8l4vrm1s6
    CSeq: 4973 ACK
    Content-Length: 0


     +0ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface send() +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:DigestAuthentication authenticate() | response generated +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport send() +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport sending message:

    INVITE sip:cliente@mydomain.com SIP/2.0
    Via: SIP/2.0/WSS s56b8ft8a202.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9092781
    Max-Forwards: 69
    To: 
    From: ;tag=l4h1ovlld6
    Call-ID: 8g0sieoec4p8l4vrm1s6
    CSeq: 4974 INVITE
    Proxy-Authorization: Digest algorithm=MD5, username="studio", realm="mydomain.com", nonce="Wa7pP1mu6BO4W5JXkW+Nxa7oljqc0vr5", uri="sip:cliente@mydomain.com", response="d9ccb7729b97814451bdd03d6a1bf3d8"
    Contact: 
    Content-Type: application/sdp
    Session-Expires: 90
    Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER,INFO
    Supported: timer,ice,replaces,outbound
    User-Agent: JsSIP 3.0.13
    Content-Length: 4562

    v=0
    o=- 6638472907486122365 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    s=-
    t=0 0
    a=group:BUNDLE audio video
    a=msid-semantic: WMS dUJ22POkI6U9YcoQ7v98q6osirNG6TZCbVhx
    m=audio 59208 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
    c=IN IP4 user_ip
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=candidate:2017461514 1 udp 2122262783 2804:d49:c4f:7f00:3d04:9c24:2401:1d42 59353 typ host generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:3022624816 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.1.4 59208 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:918813178 1 tcp 1518283007 2804:d49:c4f:7f00:3d04:9c24:2401:1d42 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:4205470912 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.1.4 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:494278629 1 udp 1685987071 user_ip 59208 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.4 rport 59208 generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
    a=ice-ufrag:60LN
    a=ice-pwd:tuTNIbAEQw/mkZX/vYKmsdM1
    a=ice-options:trickle
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 6F:B8:BF:D1:54:8F:3F:5C:5F:23:0D:48:4D:91:DC:12:CB:C3:08:73:F6:C7:CF:8E:F6:63:75:AC:C7:DB:97:5A
    a=setup:actpass
    a=mid:audio
    a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
    a=sendrecv
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
    a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
    a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
    a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
    a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
    a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
    a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
    a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
    a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
    a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
    a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
    a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
    a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
    a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
    a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
    a=ssrc:1472011457 cname:crtk8ri1ZT46Zj4D
    a=ssrc:1472011457 msid:dUJ22POkI6U9YcoQ7v98q6osirNG6TZCbVhx 86b888be-6f9a-4972-9fa7-1563d105d285
    a=ssrc:1472011457 mslabel:dUJ22POkI6U9YcoQ7v98q6osirNG6TZCbVhx
    a=ssrc:1472011457 label:86b888be-6f9a-4972-9fa7-1563d105d285
    m=video 33253 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98 100 102 127 97 99 101 125
    c=IN IP4 user_ip
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=candidate:2017461514 1 udp 2122262783 2804:d49:c4f:7f00:3d04:9c24:2401:1d42 43405 typ host generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:3022624816 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.1.4 33253 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:918813178 1 tcp 1518283007 2804:d49:c4f:7f00:3d04:9c24:2401:1d42 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:4205470912 1 tcp 1518214911 192.168.1.4 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:494278629 1 udp 1685987071 user_ip 33253 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.4 rport 33253 generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
    a=ice-ufrag:60LN
    a=ice-pwd:tuTNIbAEQw/mkZX/vYKmsdM1
    a=ice-options:trickle
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 6F:B8:BF:D1:54:8F:3F:5C:5F:23:0D:48:4D:91:DC:12:CB:C3:08:73:F6:C7:CF:8E:F6:63:75:AC:C7:DB:97:5A
    a=setup:actpass
    a=mid:video
    a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
    a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
    a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
    a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
    a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
    a=sendrecv
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtcp-rsize
    a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
    a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
    a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
    a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
    a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
    a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
    a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
    a=rtpmap:102 red/90000
    a=rtpmap:127 ulpfec/90000
    a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:97 apt=96
    a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:99 apt=98
    a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:101 apt=100
    a=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:125 apt=102
    a=ssrc-group:FID 1005898268 1803705457
    a=ssrc:1005898268 cname:crtk8ri1ZT46Zj4D
    a=ssrc:1005898268 msid:dUJ22POkI6U9YcoQ7v98q6osirNG6TZCbVhx 700a8532-4147-4891-9bad-e1446d27a7e3
    a=ssrc:1005898268 mslabel:dUJ22POkI6U9YcoQ7v98q6osirNG6TZCbVhx
    a=ssrc:1005898268 label:700a8532-4147-4891-9bad-e1446d27a7e3
    a=ssrc:1803705457 cname:crtk8ri1ZT46Zj4D
    a=ssrc:1803705457 msid:dUJ22POkI6U9YcoQ7v98q6osirNG6TZCbVhx 700a8532-4147-4891-9bad-e1446d27a7e3
    a=ssrc:1803705457 mslabel:dUJ22POkI6U9YcoQ7v98q6osirNG6TZCbVhx
    a=ssrc:1803705457 label:700a8532-4147-4891-9bad-e1446d27a7e3

     +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface send() +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:InviteClientTransaction Timer D expired for transaction z9hG4bK3599232 +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface received WebSocket message +256ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport received text message:

    SIP/2.0 100 trying -- your call is important to us
    Via: SIP/2.0/WSS s56b8ft8a202.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9092781;rport=52968;received=user_ip
    To: 
    From: ;tag=l4h1ovlld6
    Call-ID: 8g0sieoec4p8l4vrm1s6
    CSeq: 4974 INVITE
    Server: kamailio (5.0.2 (x86_64/linux))
    Content-Length: 0


     +2ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession receiveInviteResponse() +4ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface received WebSocket message +236ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport received text message:

    SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
    Record-Route: 
    Via: SIP/2.0/WSS s56b8ft8a202.invalid;rport=52968;received=user_ip;branch=z9hG4bK9092781
    To: ;tag=31g49jluo5
    From: ;tag=l4h1ovlld6
    Call-ID: 8g0sieoec4p8l4vrm1s6
    CSeq: 4974 INVITE
    Contact: 
    Supported: timer,ice,replaces,outbound
    Content-Length: 0


     +0ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession receiveInviteResponse() +11ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Dialog new UAC dialog created with status EARLY +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession session progress +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession emit "progress" +0ms
    studio.html:47 call is in progress
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface received WebSocket message +13ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport received text message:

    SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
    Record-Route: 
    Via: SIP/2.0/WSS s56b8ft8a202.invalid;rport=52968;received=user_ip;branch=z9hG4bK9092781
    To: ;tag=col67d76sd
    From: ;tag=l4h1ovlld6
    Call-ID: 8g0sieoec4p8l4vrm1s6
    CSeq: 4974 INVITE
    Contact: 
    Supported: timer,ice,replaces,outbound
    Content-Length: 0


     +0ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession receiveInviteResponse() +3ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Dialog new UAC dialog created with status EARLY +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession session progress +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession emit "progress" +0ms
    studio.html:47 call is in progress
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface received WebSocket message +970ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport received text message:

    SIP/2.0 200 OK
    Record-Route: 
    Via: SIP/2.0/WSS s56b8ft8a202.invalid;rport=52968;received=user_ip;branch=z9hG4bK9092781
    To: ;tag=col67d76sd
    From: ;tag=l4h1ovlld6
    Call-ID: 8g0sieoec4p8l4vrm1s6
    CSeq: 4974 INVITE
    Contact: 
    Session-Expires: 90;refresher=uas
    Supported: timer,ice,replaces,outbound
    Content-Type: application/sdp
    Content-Length: 3488

    v=0
    o=- 7893961123526845657 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    s=-
    t=0 0
    a=group:BUNDLE audio video
    a=msid-semantic: WMS Da9cH0TX7VgXBzx7mT2oeR4Vn13LXAs2Pv0v
    m=audio 39767 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
    c=IN IP4 192.168.1.4
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=candidate:2017461514 1 udp 2122262783 2804:d49:c4f:7f00:3d04:9c24:2401:1d42 44797 typ host generation 0 network-id 2 network-cost 10
    a=candidate:3022624816 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.1.4 39767 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
    a=ice-ufrag:vmC5
    a=ice-pwd:G/Wna7yMfjsWX5VikldsTqcU
    a=ice-options:trickle
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 1A:D6:55:36:DE:08:74:F8:A6:EB:62:60:2D:12:76:BF:C6:43:C4:B1:80:F0:4E:9D:18:27:DD:A3:A5:01:41:DE
    a=setup:active
    a=mid:audio
    a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
    a=sendrecv
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
    a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
    a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
    a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
    a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
    a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
    a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
    a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
    a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
    a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
    a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
    a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
    a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
    a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
    a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
    a=ssrc:3252687330 cname:zgqsykKoYwrKdOyg
    a=ssrc:3252687330 msid:Da9cH0TX7VgXBzx7mT2oeR4Vn13LXAs2Pv0v 7212ed0f-a221-471a-8493-bdfae85745af
    a=ssrc:3252687330 mslabel:Da9cH0TX7VgXBzx7mT2oeR4Vn13LXAs2Pv0v
    a=ssrc:3252687330 label:7212ed0f-a221-471a-8493-bdfae85745af
    m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 98 100 102 127 97 99 101 125
    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=ice-ufrag:vmC5
    a=ice-pwd:G/Wna7yMfjsWX5VikldsTqcU
    a=ice-options:trickle
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 1A:D6:55:36:DE:08:74:F8:A6:EB:62:60:2D:12:76:BF:C6:43:C4:B1:80:F0:4E:9D:18:27:DD:A3:A5:01:41:DE
    a=setup:active
    a=mid:video
    a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
    a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
    a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
    a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
    a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
    a=sendrecv
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtcp-rsize
    a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
    a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
    a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
    a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
    a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
    a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
    a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
    a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
    a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
    a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
    a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
    a=rtpmap:102 red/90000
    a=rtpmap:127 ulpfec/90000
    a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:97 apt=96
    a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:99 apt=98
    a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:101 apt=100
    a=rtpmap:125 rtx/90000
    a=fmtp:125 apt=102
    a=ssrc-group:FID 4242944791 2335887466
    a=ssrc:4242944791 cname:zgqsykKoYwrKdOyg
    a=ssrc:4242944791 msid:Da9cH0TX7VgXBzx7mT2oeR4Vn13LXAs2Pv0v 590afe5a-5a28-472e-9865-7531f7ac7e68
    a=ssrc:4242944791 mslabel:Da9cH0TX7VgXBzx7mT2oeR4Vn13LXAs2Pv0v
    a=ssrc:4242944791 label:590afe5a-5a28-472e-9865-7531f7ac7e68
    a=ssrc:2335887466 cname:zgqsykKoYwrKdOyg
    a=ssrc:2335887466 msid:Da9cH0TX7VgXBzx7mT2oeR4Vn13LXAs2Pv0v 590afe5a-5a28-472e-9865-7531f7ac7e68
    a=ssrc:2335887466 mslabel:Da9cH0TX7VgXBzx7mT2oeR4Vn13LXAs2Pv0v
    a=ssrc:2335887466 label:590afe5a-5a28-472e-9865-7531f7ac7e68

     +0ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession receiveInviteResponse() +5ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Dialog dialog 8g0sieoec4p8l4vrm1s6l4h1ovlld6col67d76sd  changed to CONFIRMED state +0ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession emit "sdp" +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession session accepted +13ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession emit "accepted" +0ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession sendRequest() +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession:Request new | ACK +0ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport send() +3ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport sending message:

    ACK sip:8s8620l1@ki4arifj28f6.invalid;alias=user_ip~52958~6;transport=ws SIP/2.0
    Route: 
    Via: SIP/2.0/WSS s56b8ft8a202.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK9046520
    Max-Forwards: 69
    To: ;tag=col67d76sd
    From: ;tag=l4h1ovlld6
    Call-ID: 8g0sieoec4p8l4vrm1s6
    CSeq: 4974 ACK
    Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER,INFO
    Supported: outbound
    User-Agent: JsSIP 3.0.13
    Content-Length: 0


     +3ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface send() +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession session confirmed +3ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession emit "confirmed" +1ms
    studio.html:57 call confirmed
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession acceptAndTerminate() +2ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession sendRequest() +0ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession:Request new | ACK +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport send() +2ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport sending message:

    ACK sip:8s8620l1@ki4arifj28f6.invalid;alias=user_ip~52958~6;transport=ws SIP/2.0
    Route: 
    Via: SIP/2.0/WSS s56b8ft8a202.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK6032459
    Max-Forwards: 69
    To: ;tag=col67d76sd
    From: ;tag=l4h1ovlld6
    Call-ID: 8g0sieoec4p8l4vrm1s6
    CSeq: 4974 ACK
    Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER,INFO
    Supported: outbound
    User-Agent: JsSIP 3.0.13
    Content-Length: 0


     +0ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface send() +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession sendRequest() +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession:Request new | BYE +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport send() +4ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport sending message:

    BYE sip:8s8620l1@ki4arifj28f6.invalid;alias=user_ip~52958~6;transport=ws SIP/2.0
    Route: 
    Via: SIP/2.0/WSS s56b8ft8a202.invalid;branch=z9hG4bK7228331
    Max-Forwards: 69
    To: ;tag=col67d76sd
    From: ;tag=l4h1ovlld6
    Call-ID: 8g0sieoec4p8l4vrm1s6
    CSeq: 4975 BYE
    Reason: SIP ;cause=488; text="Not Acceptable Here"
    Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,BYE,UPDATE,MESSAGE,OPTIONS,REFER,INFO
    Supported: outbound
    User-Agent: JsSIP 3.0.13
    Content-Length: 0


     +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface send() +0ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession session failed +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession close() +2ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession emit "failed" +0ms
    studio.html:51 call failed with cause: Bad Media Description
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23206 JsSIP:ERROR:RTCSession emit "peerconnection:setremotedescriptionfailed" [error:TypeError: session.connection.getSenders is not a function
        at RTCSession.confirmed (studio.html:58)
        at RTCSession.EventEmitter.emit (jssip-3.0.13.js:21743)
        at RTCSession.confirmed (jssip-3.0.13.js:16496)
        at jssip-3.0.13.js:15935
        at ] +2ms
    debug @ jssip-3.0.13.js:23206
    (anonymous) @ jssip-3.0.13.js:15941
    Promise rejected (async)
    (anonymous) @ jssip-3.0.13.js:15937
    Promise resolved (async)
    receiveInviteResponse @ jssip-3.0.13.js:15927
    receiveResponse @ jssip-3.0.13.js:15696
    receiveResponse @ jssip-3.0.13.js:17661
    InviteClientTransaction.receiveResponse @ jssip-3.0.13.js:18699
    onTransportData @ jssip-3.0.13.js:20593
    onData @ jssip-3.0.13.js:19315
    onMessage @ jssip-3.0.13.js:21413
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:WebSocketInterface received WebSocket message +412ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:Transport received text message:

    SIP/2.0 200 OK
    Via: SIP/2.0/WSS s56b8ft8a202.invalid;rport=52968;received=user_ip;branch=z9hG4bK7228331
    To: ;tag=col67d76sd
    From: ;tag=l4h1ovlld6
    Call-ID: 8g0sieoec4p8l4vrm1s6
    CSeq: 4975 BYE
    Supported: outbound
    Content-Length: 0


     +1ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession:Request onSuccessResponse +2ms
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:RTCSession terminate() +17s
    jssip-3.0.13.js:14282 Uncaught exception {code: 2, name: "INVALID_STATE_ERROR", status: 8, message: "Invalid status: 8"}
    RTCSession.terminate @ jssip-3.0.13.js:14282
    (anonymous) @ jssip-3.0.13.js:15118
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:InviteClientTransaction Timer B expired for transaction z9hG4bK9092781 +13s
    jssip-3.0.13.js:23030 JsSIP:InviteClientTransaction Timer M expired for transaction z9hG4bK9092781 +2s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my mistake was because I didn't using `answer(options)` after make a call. Now my code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As weird as it may seem, this problem arrived to me when I was trying to log the user agent to the console with `console.log(JSON.stringify(ua))` where `ua` is of type `UA` from JS Sip.

After removing that line or logging to the console without using `JSON.strigify` method, the call worked.